# Костная и костяная мука — есть ли разница?

Tags: семантика, паронимы

Из словаря паронимов:

> **Костяной** — сделанный из кости; добываемый из кости животных;
>   **Костный** — прил. к сущ. кость; добываемый из костей.

Разницу между *костной* болезнью, *костным* жиром и *костяной* фигуркой (то есть сделанной из кости) я понимаю, а вот в случае муки ответить затрудняюсь. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому и сомневаетесь, что в отношении муки это не паронимы, а полные синонимы - "добываемый из кости."

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/99039/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F

Вот значение слова костяной - "сделанный из кости" - является паронимом к значению "костный"(из кости, с костью)- костный мозг, костный бульон .

Оба слова многозначные.

КОСТЯНО́Й, костяная, костяное.

1. Сделанный из кости (в 1 знач.). Костяной ножик. Костяная фигурка. Костяная нога.
2. Добываемый из кости, костей (спец.). Костяная мука (вываренная и обезжиренная кость, измельченная в порошок, употр. для удобрения). Костяной клей (получаемый вывариванием из костей, то же, что столярный клей). https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/842166